How to scale a node js application being used for sending push notification in millions like 100k-500k,Using "web-push" library vapid keys and cron
I have developed an application to send push notifications using the web-push library. I am running a cron job every 30 minutes to fetch the latest subscriptions and send notifications. Currently, I have around 100,000 subscriptions. I am using an AWS Lightsail instance with 2 GB RAM, 2 vCPUs, and a 60 GB SSD server. Sending 100,000 notifications currently takes around 15 minutes, with the CPU being fully utilized.
a. How can I achieve sending 500,000 notifications in under 5 minutes?
b. Should I use cloud functions to run the cron operation for better scalability?
c. Should I use a larger server, perhaps with 4 or 8 vCPUs?
d. How can I achieve scalability?
A code snipt -
 const push = WebPush.sendNotification(
            sub.pushSubscription,
            JSON.stringify(rawChoosedCreative),
          );

          promises.push(push);
        }

        const res = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

        res.forEach((val, ind) => {
          if (val.status === 'fulfilled') sentCount += 1;
          else if (
            val.status === 'rejected'
            && (val?.reason?.statusCode === 404 || val?.reason?.statusCode === 410)
          ) unactiveIds.push(arr[ind]._id);
          else console.log(' val status', val.status);
        });

enter image description here
Currently I am just checking different documents, of cloud, node workers. I don't what can suitable for this application

For scaling Pushpad to several millions of web push notifications per hour we have used Kubernetes. You can use it to scale horizontally. However it requires some work and handling that large volumes can be costly (especially if you need to deliver the notifications in real time).
